# Custom url 'this page include script from unauthenticated source' error

Tags: python, google-chrome, https, box-api, custom-url

I am using windows 7 and python 2.7
I am using Custom url for launching an app.
First I am opening a web page of BOX asking for user credentials for authentication. In the url, made redirect_uri = customuri://box_auth.
So, BOX sends the success code to this redirect uri which launches app  customuri.exe. 
But I am getting a shield icon Insecure content appearing in the address bar of my Google page

Hovering over the shield gives "**This page includes script from unauthenticated sources**."
On Inspect Element it shows,

*https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=opun9…yt6q707s=authenticated&redirect_uri=curlargu://box_auth' was loaded over HTTPS,
but ran insecure content from 'customuri://box_auth?state=authenticated&code=TZzZhJwlw4AbWcn5FgxvpBz5H': 
this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.*

As custom url app should be launch with customuri://box_auth in chrome browser over https. 
So, how to handle this issue.  **Issue is with chrome only**, firefox and IE working fine

customuri:// will launch an appplication as custom url. This application I had written in python language and then converted into an exe file. I had mapped customuri with the location of this exe file in registry

Answer (score 1):

The issue is **non**-secure scripts being run inside secure pages and is documented by Google here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en

As a user, you have the choice to click the shield icon in the browser bar and run the non-secure scripts or not. As a developer, you need to ensure your scripts inside secured pages are also from a secured source.

Comment: customuri:// will launch an appplication as custom url. This application I had written in python language and then converted into an exe file. I had mapped customuri with the location of this exe file in registry

Answer (score 1):

This occur when your page embed HTTP unsecured Content/Scripts into HTTPS secured environment and might be the SSL certificate is configured on Load-Balancer not application server therefore, the traffic is encrypted up to the Load-Balancer, then it’s in clear between the Load-Balancer and the application server that called SSL offloadingso i think you will require to enable mix contents in IE or load unsecure scripts in Chrome.
For more details check [this](https://mohamedelkassas.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/this-page-is-trying-to-load-scripts-from-unauthenticated-sources-when-starting-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score -2):

This is what I did, go into chrome settings, go to advanced setting and hit reset, close Chrome restart PC and its gone.